# Являясь контуженым/контуженным

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Содат был раненым/раненным.`

`Она была некрещёной/некрещённой`

`Являясь контуженым/контуженным, генерал ничего не слышал.`

`Я, будучи раненым/раненным, только мог ползти.`

Надо, по идее, писать с одним *н* – по 3-му пункту РАН: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52, – но это, по-моему, немного-таки 3-му пункту Розенталя противоречит: http://rosental-book.ru/ortho_xiii.html#sect52. (Я очень-тко запутался.)

Comment: у контуженный нет формы *контуженый*, только контужен, контужена

Comment: есть "ранящий удар", но *контужащий* - не получится.